# React : How to uncheck all elements <input type='checkbox'/> when I want to reset a state

Tags: reactjs

I ask this question because I didn't find the good solution for this problem.
I have the following example. I just want to apply some filters to a list of fruits when an element is checked or not.
All is working fine.
When i want to reset the selection, it works well because the default list is found but the elements are still checked.
Is there a solution for this problem?

```js
const App = () => {
const fruits = ["Tomate", "Banana", "Orange"];

  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState([]);

  const handleChangeFruit = (event) => {
    var updatedFruitList = [...checked];
    if (event.target.checked) {
      updatedFruitList = [...checked, event.target.value];
    } else {
      updatedFruitList.splice(checked.indexOf(event.target.value), 1);
    }
    setChecked(updatedFruitList);
  };

  const isCheckedFruit = (fruit) => {
    return checked.find((c) => c === fruit) ? true : false;
  };

  const handleDeleteWorld = () => {
    setChecked([]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        {fruits.map((fruit) => (
          <div key={fruit}>
            <input type="checkbox" value={fruit} onChange={handleChangeFruit} />
            <label>{fruit}</label>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>

      <div>
        <p>List :</p>
        {fruits.map((fruit) => (
          <div  key={fruit}>
            {(isCheckedFruit(fruit) || !checked.length) && (
              <p>{fruit}</p>
            )}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>

      <div>
        <button onClick={handleDeleteWorld}>Reset checked elements</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


    ReactDOM.render( <
      App / > ,
      document.getElementById("root")
    );
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: In react it's practice to use `checked` attribute in element itself for manipulating checkbox. `<input type='checkbox' checked={i.isChecked} onClick={toggleIsCheck} />`

Comment: You mean I have to create another state for the `checked` attribute of the `input`?

Comment: Yes, here's the explenation for Controlled Components by Reactjs itself https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components